# Xcode: TAB key for indenting selection

Tags: keyboard, xcode, keybindings

I hope that somebody here can suggest me a way to make the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key indent a text selection (i.e., could be multi-line and not just one line) in Xcode.

In Xcode preferences, I set <kbd>TAB</kbd> as the shortcut for the "Shift right" function but it does not work: instead of indenting, it deletes the text.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **BetterTouchTool** to rebind <kbd>TAB ⇥</kbd> key to <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> only for Xcode.app. BetterTouchTool can be downloaded [here](http://www.bettertouchtool.net). This is how this should look like:

[image] I've tested this and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, it requires BetterTouchTool to run in background. I hope there is a lighter solution.